# How to determine the range of the following function $\frac{x}{1+ |x|}$?

Tags: functions

How to determine the range of the following function $\frac{x}{1+ |x|}$?

when I calculated it, it was $\mathbb{R}$, but my professor said that the range is ]-1,1[, could anyone explain for me why?

thanks!

Comment: Why do you think it's $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: 1) I divided the function into 2 parts to get rid of the absolute value @Dylan

Comment: 2)Then I started with $x \geq 0$ and reached the shape of the function where also the shape of the function was $\geq 0$.@Dylan

Comment: 3) I repeated the same step for $x < 0$reached the shape of the function where also the shape of the function was $< 0$.

Comment: It's true that the function is $\ge 0$ for $x \ge 0$, but does it grow without bound? Or is there a limit as $x \to \infty$?

Comment: with me it grow without bound @Dylan

Comment: No it doesn't. See what happens when $x$ is very large. What is the function value when $x=100$? when $x=1000$?

Comment: yeah I got your idea @Dylan

Comment: You're very welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that $\large|\frac {x}{1+|x|}|=\frac {|x|}{1+|x|}=1-\frac {1}{1+|x|} \lt 1.$

$\therefore |\frac {x}{1+|x|}| \lt 1 \Rightarrow -1 \lt \frac {x}{1+|x|} \lt 1$.

Comment: I'd use the strict inequality instead of $\le$. The function can never equal $1$

Comment: @Dylan Yes yes you are right.

Comment: @Error404 $|f(x)|\le a$ doesn't necessary imply that $-a\le f(x)\le a$. For example, consider $f(x)=e^x-\frac14$ for $x\le0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+ |x|}$. Then:  $|f(x)|=\frac{|x|}{1+ |x|} \le 1$, hence

$f( \mathbb R) \subseteq [-1,1]$.

Furthermore: $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=1$  and $\lim_{x \to -\infty}f(x)=-1$.

Show that $f(x) \ne 1$ and $f(x) \ne -1$ for all $x$.

Are you now in a position to derive $f( \mathbb R) =]-1,1[$ ?

Answer (score 1):

For $x\geq 0$, $\dfrac{x}{1+|x|}=\dfrac{x}{1+x}=1-\dfrac{1}{1+x}$, it is increasing on $[0,\infty)$, so it maps onto $[0,1)$. Similarly you can deal with $(-\infty,0]$.

Comment: You can also get the answer for $x \leq 0$ by using the fact that the function is odd.

Answer (score 1):

check : $1+|x|\neq 0\Rightarrow |x|\neq-1$, which is true for all $x$.

Now,

when $0\leq x<\infty , y=\frac{x}{1+x}, x<x+1\Rightarrow 0\leq y<1...(I)$

when $-\infty <x<0 , y=\frac{x}{1-x}$ ,

|numerator|<|denominator|, so $|y|$ lies between $0$ and $1$, but since numerator is negative and denominator is positive,$-1<y<0...(II)$

combining $(I),(II)$ we get $-1<y<1$